# Visual Studio can't detect WDK headers for Windows 10, throwing error can't detect ntddk.h header

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2015, sdk, wdk

Apparently there's a lot of potential problems with Visual Studio 2015, Windows Driver Kit for Windows 10, and Windows Software Development Kit for Windows 10 not all meshing well together. I'm getting this error, and all the troubleshooting I've tried from online has belly-flopped.

> `fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'ntddk.h': No such file or directory`

Is there a known happy-path for installing these three together? Or some other way to fix this issue that can scale?

---

#### Similar questions & answers that didn't work

This question seems to have fallen off by the wayside, but might be the same root-cause, but there wasn't enough info provided: [Visual Studio 2015 WDK Not Working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39491827/visual-studio-2015-wdk-not-working)

I won't accept any answers [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35777922/cannot-open-include-file-ntddk-h) that hard-code the SDK's version as I can't guarantee which 10.x version will be installed across all developer machines, only that they will have a Win 10 DK and SDK.

Then there's this [Matching-versions answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31642528/3543437) that was incorrectly accepted, as there is no corresponding WDK version for the current WSDK available to download from Microsoft. Current WDK available online is `10.0.14393` and WSDK is `10.0.15063.468`

Last but not least, [this solution](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowshardware/en-US/1fa43cc7-a82d-4dd3-8d28-f76fe2d7593e/hardware-development-kits-for-windows-10-version-1703-april-2017?forum=wdk) from MSDN that also failed to work.

Comment: are you setup vc++ directories for include files ?

Comment: Visual Studio 2015, Update 3, all C++ options installed with Custom installation option instead of Typical/Default.

Comment: For the Windows 10 SDK, all options were checked.

Comment: but are you set paths like `c:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.15063.0\km` or like this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, this ended up being a combination of a couple things that needed to happen in a specific order. I did all of these previously, but not in the required order while I was messing around with installing and uninstalling some of the kits. I'm not 100% sure this order is required. However I did notice that all the kits must be installed before running Repair, even if the WDK 1703 is the last kit to be installed:

1. Install WDK `10.0.14393` for Windows 10, version 1607
2. Install the Windows SDK `10.0.15063` for Windows 10, version 1703
3. Install WDK `10.0.15063` for Windows 10, version 1703
4. Run Repair on the 1703 version of the WDK `10.0.15063`

All kits can be found here: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/windows-driver-kit

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://www.windrvr.com/2015/05/11/wdk-installation-tips/) you can find solid, proven instructions for installing WDK with VS 2015. For any issues with newer kits and VS2017, the genuine official [Microsoft WDK forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/home?forum=wdk) is to your service.

Comment: Everyone is entitled to their opinion. Instead of the links, I could formulate my answer this way: 1. Setup of WDK + VS2015  does work, but is bristle. Carefully read instructions; 2. If it still does not work, the Microsoft forums are the best place to ask, because real MS engineers answer there.  That['s the answer. Thanks for your understanding.